# Check if a input box is empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

How can I check if a given input control is empty? I know there is `$pristine` property on the field which tells that if a given field is empty initially but what if when someone fill the field and yanks the whole content again?

I think above feature is necessary as its important for telling the user that field is required.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[Quite simple](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZZwkvLiBU912xsHpygjy?p=preview):

```
<input ng-model="somefield">
<span ng-show="!somefield.length">Please enter something!</span>
<span ng-show="somefield.length">Good boy!</span>
```

You could also use `ng-hide="somefield.length"` instead of `ng-show="!somefield.length"` if that reads more naturally for you.

---

A better alternative might be to really take advantage of the [form abilities of Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.text):

```
<form name="myform">
  <input name="myfield" ng-model="somefield" ng-minlength="5" required>
  <span ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.required">Please enter something!</span>
  <span ng-show="!myform.myfield.$error.required">Good boy!</span>
</form>
```

[Updated Plnkr here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hfIWCfZkpPkOKo1L6BhV?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, the length property is available only when the field is valid. For  example I set the field's `minlength` to 5 and enter only three chars then the length property will not be available.

Comment: @vivekpoddar [Angular should be forgiving](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) about that though, so when `length` is not available then it evaluates to `undefined` which is interpreted as false. If you're trying to do the check in a controller, i.e. in JavaScript and not in an Angular expression, then it's another story where you need to handle the forgiving yourself. Note that there is also a `required` attribute which might do exactly what you want: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.text

Comment: @vivekpoddar Updated with `required` example.

Answer (score 14):

Even you don't need to measure the length of string. A ! operator can solve everything for you. Remember always:
!(empty string) = true
!(some string) = false

So you could write:

```
<input ng-model="somefield">
<span ng-show="!somefield">Sorry, the field is empty!</span>
<span ng-hide="!somefield">Thanks. Successfully validated!</span>
```

Comment: Yeah Jonatas it seems confusing because it is same check but actually these are different. the first one is ng-show and the second one is ng-hide. So they are reverse! :-) you also can use both ng-show but with different checks. one with not (!) and another one without not (!).

Answer (score 6):

***Another approach is using regex , as show below , you can use the empty regex pattern and achieve the same using ng-pattern***

HTML :

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="formController">
 <form name="myform">
 <input name="myfield" ng-model="somefield" ng-minlength="5" ng-pattern="mypattern" required>
 <span ng-show="myform.myfield.$error.pattern">Please enter!</span>
 <span ng-show="!myform.myfield.$error.pattern">great!</span>
</form>
```

Controller:@formController :

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
App.controller('formController', function ($scope) {              
  $scope.mypattern = /^\s*$/g;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer didn't work with **Angular 6**. So following is how I resolved it.
Lets say this is how I defined my input box -

```html
<input type="number" id="myTextBox" name="myTextBox"
 [(ngModel)]="response.myTextBox"
            #myTextBox="ngModel">
```

To check if the field is empty or not this should be the script.

```html
<div *ngIf="!myTextBox.value" style="color:red;">
 Your field is empty
</div>
```

Do note the subtle difference between the above answer and this answer. I have added an additional attribute `.value` after my input name `myTextBox`. 
I don't know if the above answer worked for above version of Angular, but for **Angular 6** this is how it should be done.

Some more explanation on why this check works; when there is no value present in the input box the default value of `myTextBox.value` will be `undefined`. As soon as you enter some text, your text becomes the new value of `myTextBox.value`.

When your check is `!myTextBox.value` it is checking that the value is undefined or not, it is equivalent to `myTextBox.value == undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

To auto check a checkbox if input field is not empty.

```
 <md-content>
            <md-checkbox ng-checked="myField.length"> Other </md-checkbox>
            <input  ng-model="myField" placeholder="Please Specify" type="text">
 </md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your textbox is a Required field and have some regex pattern to match and has minlength and maxlength

**TestBox code**

```
<input type="text" name="myfieldname" ng-pattern="/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="50" class="classname" ng-model="model.myfieldmodel">
```

**Ng-Class to Add**

```
ng-class="{ 'err' :  myform.myfieldname.$invalid || (myform.myfieldname.$touched && !model.myfieldmodel.length) }"
```