# Evaluating an expression which contains an expression

Tags: angularjs, expression

I am a newbie to **Angular js** and I just started doing a project in Angular JS.
Let me give you a brief idea about my application. I have a json data which contains data of some nodes, which form a hierarchy. I am using to display this data. So It will take one node at a time and display based on the data in it. I need to display a select field based on the data.

Everything worked fine until I need to display error messages, if the user doesn't select a value in the field. It should be displayed on that particular node. For this I should identify each node( *as this is a template*). I mapped the id in the data as the name of the select tag, made the tag as required and written a span which displays an error message.

This span will be displayed based on the condition

> $error.required

.

The code snippet is as follows.

```
<form class='css-form form-search' name="myForm" novalidate>
......
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mynodetemplate">
........
<select name="{{node.id}}" ng-model="node.attributeId" ng-options="attribute.id as attribute.name for attribute in attributes" ng-show ="node.showData" required>
       <option value="">Select an Attribute</option>
</select>
<span ng-show=”myForm.node.id.$error.required" style="text-align:center; color:red">Please select</span>

'''''''
</script>
..........
<div ui-tree id="tree-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="nodes">
            <li ng-repeat="node in nodes” ui-tree-node ng-include="mynodetemplate”></li>
       </ol>
</div>
```

..........

But I am not able to give the correct expression here-
ng-show=”myForm.node.id.$error.required"

I have tried so many ways to evaluate the correct expression, but its not working.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you use a dot in a name attribute value? Seems like you are just asking for problems

Comment: What is myForm.node.id.$error.required?  To show if the selection is empty,  why not just use node.attributeId == ''

Comment: @charlietfl it was a mistake. I corrected that.

Comment: @JamesWaddington so the validation can be done easily. The value myForm.node.id.$error.required is true, if the user is not selected anything in that drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691915/227775)

What I have done is that , I will just check whether value exists in the modal or not, or its length.

A sample snippet from the answer is as follows

```
<input ng-model="somefield">
<span ng-show="!somefield.length">Please enter something!</span>
<span ng-show="somefield.length">Good boy!</span>
```

Thanks @Supr for the answer.

I dont know why the form validation is not working though :(

Answer (score 0):

Just as in JavaScript, if you want the name of an object attribute to be `node.id`, you can't just write

```
object.node.id
```

because that references the attribute `id` of the attribute `node`of the object. So you're forced to use

```
object['node.id']
```

So your expression should be

```
ng-show="myForm['node.id'].$error.required"
```

But I agree with charlieftl in the comments. You're making your own life difficult by choosing a name containing a dot. Just rename it `nodeId`, and you can use

```
ng-show="myForm.nodeId.$error.required"
```

EDIT:

The name is now in fact a dynamic name. So, in JavaScript you would use

```
object[node.id]
```

In the expression, since the scope is implicit, you would use

```
ng-show="myForm[node.id].$error.required"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually node.id is not a static name JB. I was trying to give the value inside the node.id. I have made correction in the code snippet. Now the name ="{{node.id}}"

Comment: @dasrohith it should work. Provide a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, ours is a isolated environment. Its very difficult to reproduce the snippet in plunker. I am sorry for that. Thanks a lot for your help