# How to call a function when input is cleared in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, input

I know Angular has [simple syntax to display messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691778/check-if-a-input-box-is-empty) or update css, but what I'm trying to do is actually call a function.

```
<input ng-model="somefield">
<span ng-show="!somefield.length">Please enter something!</span>
<span ng-show="somefield.length">Good boy!</span>
```

---

This is my model `vm.tagSearching = ''` I can detect when I start typing in the input and see the value update. However once I get to the last letter, and I delete that I don't get an update.

I tried using `$scope.watch`

```
$scope.$watch('vm.tagSearching', function() {
   alert('hey, var has changed!');
});
```

However this only fires once as the app initializes, but never again, even while typing.

**Markup**

```
<input class="tag-search-input"
       type="text"
       placeholder="Search Tags"
       ng-model="tgs.tagSearching"
       typeahead="t for t in tgs.fuzzyTagSearch($viewValue)">
```

---

**Controller**

```
function fuzzyTagSearch(word) {
    console.log('fuzzyTagSearch',word);
    if (word.length > 2) {
        ApiFactory.getSearchResults(word).then(function(data) {
            console.log('data',data.data.ticker_tags);
            vm.terms = data.data.ticker_tags;
        });
    }
}
```

How would you accomplish this? I need to detect when the input is clear when the user backspaces / deletes all the letters so that I can reset the table.

Comment: Seems your `fuzzyTagSearch` doesn't return anything

Comment: I actually found a work around, sorta kinda, but not really hacky `word.length < 2` then I can call a function that way. However I'm still wondering if there is a better/more Angular way to accomplish clear input detection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply set up an [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive.

```
<input ng-model="tgs.tagSearching" ng-change="tgs.detectEmpty()">
```

---

```
vm.detectEmpty = function() {
    if (vm.tagSearching.trim().length === 0) {
        // it's empty
    }
}
```