# How to check if file input is empty in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

Like in the title, how I can check if the file input is empty? And bind the result to $scope.

Comment: actually searching for the answer will net you results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a input box is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691778/check-if-a-input-box-is-empty)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Natively you can't, because file uploading are more complex than that.

In order to trigger and upload of a file you have to use a multipart request which is different from a simple AJAX JSON request.

Of course since angularJS is a very popular framework you have a plugin for this : https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. You will find every thing you need :

1. How to upload a file
2. How to restrict a file (content type, weight, ...).
3. It even show some use case about how handling that on server side for Spring/Rails/NodeJS/PHP,...