# AngularJS How to dynamically get the ng-model value of inputs in a form or whatever

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I have a form containing inputs with a ng-model defined for each of them :

```
<form>
<input type="date" ng-model="dateFilterInput" id="dateFilter" class="...">
<select class="..." id="authorFilter" ng-model="authorFilterInput">   
...
</select>
<input type="text" class="..." id="categoryFilter" ng-model="categoryFilterInput">
</form>
```

As my form could get dynamically further inputs (using ng-repeat), I want to check in each input if the value is empty **using ng-model dynamically**

I'm doing a foreach loop for each inputs in the form, and calling this function with the ng-modal name (string) as parameter :

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(ngModelInput) {
      if(modelInput == "" || typeof modelInput == 'undefined') {
        //do something if field is empty...
      }
};
```

or

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(ngModelInput) {
      if($scope.modelInput == "" || typeof $scope.modelInput == 'undefined') {
        //do something if field is empty...
      }
};
```

But this doesn't work because ngModelInput is a string.

**For example :**

Imagine `ngModelInput = "dateFilterInput"`

How to translate this :

`$scope.ngModelInput` (How to write it ?)

to make this :

```
$scope.dateFilterInput
```

Hope you see what I mean ^^

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a input box is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691778/check-if-a-input-box-is-empty)

Comment: Use === instead of == too, although that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: @Matheno Thanks for the link but this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the isEmpty function as below and that should solve your problem.
Do not use ng as prefix to any variable as ng is a angular reserved keyword and it may confuse other developers.

```
$scope.isEmpty = function(modelInput) {
      if($scope[modelInput] == "" || typeof $scope[modelInput] == 'undefined') {
        //do something if field is empty...
      }
};
```

The above code takes whatever the parameter(string) you pass to the `isEmpty` function and checks for that particular name in the $scope object and gives you the value based on it.

Comment: Yes this is the solution that I was looking for ! Thanks for the tips also @SSG !

Comment: @SSG what if we have $scope.something.abc what would be the equivalent if something is not dynamic and abc is. And respectively if both are dynamic,I get error Unexpected token [ when only abc is dynamic